# Problems with code in JavaScript with loops

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I learn loops in JavaScript with for-loop and I have this code (j) that does not work with me I don’t know why?

```
let start = 1;
let end = 6;
let breaker = 2;

for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  for (let j = breaker; j <= end; i++) {
    console.log(j);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never increase `j` thus you get endless loop, try replacing

```
for(let j = breaker; j <= end; i++)
```

using

```
for(let j = breaker; j <= end; j+=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You changed `i` and `j` in inner loop

```js
let start = 1;    
let end = 6;    
let breaker = 2;


for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) 
{
    console.log("i => ", i);
    for(let j = breaker; j <= end; j++)
    {
        console.log("j => ", j);
    }
}
```

`